# Sorting results of query when using AppSync and Dynamo

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have a basic table with a timestamp and a few fields as I am looking at AppSync, and I connected the table using the AppSync console and it created a schema for me and querying works as expected. As the data is time series based I wanted to be able to get the latest record, and so through the dynamo console I can run a query using the index and check the box "Sort Descending" and this returns the data with the latest record at the top.

So to try to do the same with AppSync I changed the schema to include `scanIndexForward` and I have tried toggling the value between `true` and `false` like so:

```
type Query {
    getCurrentPeriodQueryTable(scanIndexForward: Boolean, Id: String!, At: String!): CurrentPeriodQueryTable
    listCurrentPeriodQueryTables(
        scanIndexForward: Boolean,
        filter: TableCurrentPeriodQueryTableFilterInput,
        limit: Int,
        nextToken: String
    ): CurrentPeriodQueryTableConnection
}
```

This does not seem to do anything, the results are always returned in the same order, regardless of whether the value is `true`, or `false`, however sorting in the dynamo console does seem to work. Below is the  query:

```
query MyQuery {
  listCurrentPeriodQueryTables(scanIndexForward: true, limit: 1) {
    nextToken
    items {
      TimeStamp
      Value
    }
  }
}
```

Should this property be changing the sort order of the result of the query?

Comment: Is the timestamp field your table's SORT key?

Comment: Yes it is the sort key on the table, so when I sort in the dynamo console I get the expected order.

Comment: Are you sure your AppSync resolver is applying the `scanIndexForward` property to the DynamoDB SDK call?

Comment: I am not, I am using the autogenerated code which was created by referencing the table as a datasource, and the documentation seemed to suggest `scanIndexForward` is supported but I do think this is the issue, its not being applied, although I cannot see why not.

Comment: The documentation I am referring to is this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb.html#aws-appsync-resolver-mapping-template-reference-dynamodb-query

Where the query section seems to suggest `scanIndexForward` is a valid property.

Comment: Some of my confusion has been caused by using the wizard to automatically create the types and resolvers for the table, I do not have the option to create a "unit resolver" using VTL and only have the pipeline resolver option.

Answer (score 0):

`scanIndexForward` is set to `True` by default, so I would expect that there would be no change to the order when you explicitly set it to `True`.

Be mindful that `scanIndexForward` will only sort items based on the Sort Key, for that reason I assume that the timestamp you want to sort on is your Sort Key.

If thats the case, then you can set `scanIndexForward = false`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-ScanIndexForward

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I am flipping it between `true` and `false` and the order is not changing at all. I do want to sort by the sort key, which is the timestamp, and the checkbox on the console sorts the records in the order I want to get through AppSync.